# How do Kafka Quotas work?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

My question is:
If I set my quota for 1 MB/sec, How much does a multi-broker cluster get? (For Example, take 2 brokers)
Will the speed be 1MB/sec per each broker (or) 0.5 MB/sec for each broker?

The documentation says:

> For example, if (user="test-user", client-id="test-client") has a
>   produce quota of 10MB/sec, this is shared across all producer
>   instances of user "test-user" with the client-id "test-client.

Answer (score 5):

Yes Quotas are calculated per broker. So in your example, you will get 1MB/sec on each broker.

The [Quotas Enforcement](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotasenforcement) section in the Kafka documentation says:

> By default, each unique client group receives a fixed quota as configured
>   by the cluster. **This quota is defined on a per-broker basis**. Each
>   client can utilize this quota per broker before it gets throttled. We
>   decided that defining these quotas per broker is much better than
>   having a fixed cluster wide bandwidth per client because that would
>   require a mechanism to share client quota usage among all the brokers.
>   This can be harder to get right than the quota implementation itself!